# Trying to withdraw from contract - Fail with error 'WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 1 ETH at present market ...'

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, error, frontrunning, scam

Tried to use a standard front running bot but the thing is my eth is still on the contract so I don't think I've been scammed (yet) makes no sense since my eth is still sitting there.

this is the code

https://pastebin.com/raw/D8QEX5tm

Whenever I try to withdraw it says "Fail with error 'WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 1 ETH at present market condition ...'"

This is the transaction : https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa5c1dd6c6876c2ed8ad68cde07962cc94653adf4e2336c453456ec4f65ffab46

Anyone have any assistance?

Been stuck for a couple months.

contract address https://etherscan.io/address/0x0bdD76ce3B04C22707420121fD50510D9f59bC7D

Every now and then I try to pull it out again with no luck that's why there's so many attempts.

Comment: This happened to me too. I wish I was read this before. This is the another version of it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXJ--uBIiO4 . When you send 0.6 eth to contract and push start warning says it must be 1 eth to start the bot and if you send 0.4 more eth then it says you must have to 2 eth because of the market conditions so if you send it again too then it says you must have to 5 eth. Did you find out any progress @Jason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, this again?
I'm sorry to tell you, but you got scammed.

This smart contract only does 2 things, take your eth and then send it to a hardcoded address (i.e. the scammer's address).

Your eth is still on the smart contract and has not been sent to the scammer yet, but there are no functions to get your eth back.

So it's gone, for ever.

Sorry man

EDIT: [Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/137684/beware-of-uniswap-front-running-bot-scam/137709#137709) is another post from someone else that fell for the same scam that you did. Hope this helps

Comment: You say "This smart contract only does 2 things, take your eth and then send it to a hardcoded address (i.e. the scammer's address)." 

Where are you able to see that?

Comment: The withdraw function and the start function, the only 2 functions you can call, both do the same thing: payable(manager.uniswapDepositAddress()).transfer(address(this).balance);  That manager is created in the constructor. It comes from the ipfs import happening line 8. If you look at this link, it's thousands of commented lines of code in order to confuse code noobs into falling for the scam. In the IPFS file, line 6529, there is an address that is not commented out. It's your scammer's address. Only this address can receive the eth stuck on your smart contract. You got scammed

Comment: I'm not denying that I was scammed I was just curious of exactly where it shows. Thanks for pointing it out. I am going to check it out some more. Have a good day. Crazy that I'm not able to pull it off the contract in anyway

Comment: That's how smart contract are. Once the code is deployed, you can't change it. So the scammer didn't code a contract where his victims could withdraw their money. Anyway, happy I could help. If you could mark my answer as accepted so other people find it more easily, that would be great

Comment: I see. It looks like it may work if I loaded the contract with more ETH. That return address you mentioned has some ETH on it. I'm going to see if I can scam the scammer. This is the youtube profile that the scam video is on - https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9ZYQLKnxSiAUCq29ddsjyA .  I will mark as answered. Thanks again

Comment: It won't work if you load more eth onto the contract. You will just send more eth to the scammer. Do not do that

Comment: yeah for sure. I just mean the withdraw function will actually withdraw but into his account. Right now it doesnt even function