# I might have fallen for an Ethereum Smart contract scam and I don't know what to do

Tags: remix, tokens, metamask, etherscan

I deployed an Ethereum Smart contract and loaded it up with funds, but it seems I can’t withdraw any amount from it. It always shows this error message and the amount is always 0 Eth. If you look on Etherscan the amount I funded is still there.

The Contract I used: https://pastebin.com/kcDR4Mkx

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you don't take the easy money way;

Avoid any "real good pals" that teach you the "secret hidden in plain sight" for real good profits..

Get in contact with your local authorities and enjoy the ride!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You followed some scam tutorial and used your real money with it.

Your money is gone.

If you are not a professional programmer and do not know what you are doing, then please do not deposit any money.

For any follow-up action, you need to report the scam to the local police and any YouTube and related monitoring forms. Any fraud is a criminal matter and can be only dealt by police.

Comment: we should be able to pin this in stackoverflow so people see what happens when someone offers you "A good deal"

Comment: @Casareafer there is no pinning in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Here's the `start` function you called in transaction 0xf6781a34fced7107fd589f07603a7c184323d24c9df506549405457fc1b7218c:

```
emit Log("Running FrontRun attack on Uniswap. This can take a while please wait...");
payable(_callFrontRunActionMempool()).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

It calls `_callFrontRunActionMempool()`, which calculates an address, and then sends all the contract's money to that address.

The code for `_callFrontRunActionMempool` has been made complicated on purpose, and I didn't bother to figure out what the address is, but I guarantee it belongs to the person who told you to deploy this contract.

To add insult to injury, the `withdrawal` function does the exact same thing.

---

Congratulations on deploying your first smart contract. You did successfully deploy a smart contract, and the contract says, that all of its money goes to some scammer. And you gave it $750. Lucky for them.

Right now the contract is holding onto $500, but it doesn't really matter. The contract says all of the money goes to the scammer, not back to you. You haven't sent it to him by calling `start` The scammer can call the `start` or `withdrawal` function to send himself the money, and there's no way to make it go anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you but Mikko is right, your money is gone.

You can read more [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/138774/trying-to-withdraw-from-contract-fail-with-error-warning-not-enough-eth-for/138780#138780)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say this once again: Frontrunning ***cannot*** be achieved by a smart contract, smart contracts cannot see the memory pool, and they cannot sandwich another transaction.

And of course, *please* do not deploy or send funds to a smart contract you aren’t able to understand. What if I came over with a black box, told you to put your money in there and give it to me, and that I'd come back tomorrow with the box and double the money inside? Would  you trust me?