# I’m stuck on a active trade

Tags: web3js, cpp-ethereum

I recently followed a YouTube tutorial for a frontrunningbot for uniswap and I am currently stuck on a active trade for the past two days. The contract Has .8 Eth Any clue as to what I should do ? This is what I am getting.   Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction
execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted: WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need
at least 2 ETH at present market conditions. Cannot withdraw during an active
trade, try again in about an hour... ["originalError"': { "code"': 3, "data":
"Ox08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000ac5741524e494473a2066f74206566f756768204554
4820666f722070726f66697461626c652066726f67472756e6e696e672€204
e656564206174206c6561737420322045544820617420707265736567420
6d61726b657420636f6646974696f6732e2043616e6e6f74207769746864
726177206475726966720616e206163746976652074726164652c2074727
920616761696e20696e2061626f757420616e20686f75722e2e2e000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000", "message": "execution reverted:
WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 2 ETH at
present market conditions. Cannot withdraw during an active trade, try again in
about an hour." }]

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a front running bot, it’s a scam. Your money is gone. See this: [I might have fallen for an Ethereum Smart contract scam and I don't know what to do](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140624/i-might-have-fallen-for-an-ethereum-smart-contract-scam-and-i-dont-know-what-to/140626#140626)