# Did I get scammed? Created solidity smart contract and can't withdraw

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, cpp-ethereum

Hoping this isn't the case but I created a smart contract based on a youtube video, I know feel like a moron, and glanced at the code and it seemed legit. I own the smart contract, but I can't withdraw.

Here's the contract:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x4547c4dce5f550f05f093f7ad99ec352a349afaa

I created this contract based on this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXJ--uBIiO4

Code is here:
https://pastebin.com/raw/BN1VShiZ

When I attempt to withdraw from remix I get the following error:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted: WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 2 ETH at present market conditions. Cannot withdraw during an active trade, try again in about an hour... { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "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", "message": "execution reverted: WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 2 ETH at present market conditions. Cannot withdraw during an active trade, try again in about an hour..." } }

Comment: It is a well known scam contract. Never deploy, not send funds to a contract that you can't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes unfortunately you got scammed... Sorry.

Here are two different threads I answered of people getting scammed by the same video

[Beware of "Uniswap Front Running Bot" Scam](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/137684/beware-of-uniswap-front-running-bot-scam/137709#137709)

[Trying to withdraw from contract - Fail with error 'WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 1 ETH at present market ...'](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/138774/trying-to-withdraw-from-contract-fail-with-error-warning-not-enough-eth-for/138780#138780)

Hope this helps and hope you can recover from the loss of funds